# White page on order view page.

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting this error for a while and I am clueless to what is wrong with it.
Whenever I click the view order page, I get a blank page. Now I installed some code on my index.php that displays the errors.

This is the error that I get:

```
Array
(
   [type] => 1
   [message] => Class 'Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Info' not found
   [file] => /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
   [line] => 491
)
```

This is line 491 (and context)

```
/**
 * Create block object instance based on block type
 *
 * @param string $block
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
protected function _getBlockInstance($block, array $attributes=array())
{
    if (is_string($block)) {
        if (strpos($block, '/')!==false) {
            if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
            }
        }
        if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
            $block = new $block($attributes);
        }
    }
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Seems nothing is wrong there (and why should it, its magento default code)

Now the next part is somewhat strange. I expected the class to live in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Info I looked it up. The folders Order/Info didnt exist in my folder. Nor in the fresh install zip.

What is going on and more importantly, how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi if the files doesn't exist then download the same version and check folders that files is there or not

Comment: @HardikShah Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Rathinam
Which issue of mine?